# Pagination with AWS API Gateway + DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, pagination, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I have an API Gateway `GET` endpoint that scans a DynamoDB table and retrieve results according to a Limit parameter:

```
requestTemplates:
          application/json: >-
            {
              "TableName": "employee",
              "Limit": 2
            }
```

It is properly working and the response for this request when I send a `limit = 2` is:

```
{
   "Count":2,
   "Items":[
      {
         "id":{
            "S":"18"
         },
         "department":{
            "S":"sales"
         },
         "name":{
            "S":"Roger"
         }
      },
      {
         "id":{
            "S":"16"
         },
         "department":{
            "S":"technology"
         },
         "name":{
            "S":"Petterson"
         }
      }
   ],
   "LastEvaluatedKey":{
      "id":{
         "S":"16"
      }
   },
   "ScannedCount":2
}
```

The problem is: I have 20 records stored in this table, and the `ScannedCount` and `Count` are both equal to 2.

I really need to know the count of the total amount of records I have stored in order to make a pagination frontend componenet to work.

I've looked through the documentation and a see that the expected result for this request would be `ScannedCount = 2` and `Count = 20`.

Is there a way to have it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: do you have access to the code which accesses DynamoDB?

Comment: There is no code. This is a custom non-proxy integration between API Gateway and DynamoDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only the direct integration api-gw <-> dynamodb integration, check describe - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTable.html and do two calls to get the desired data.

But I recommend using a Lambda in between Api Gateway and DynamoDB, which will facilitate the pagination.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Actually I was trying to not have to perform this additional request, but I'm getting stuck with no options left here...

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't ideal, but **if you can update your DynamoDB table schema to include an additional `total` attribute on each item** (and implement corresponding count management of that attribute), then *that would facilitate just one API Gateway request* (still no Lambda or other type of repository layer compute necessary as in the Question).

I say probably not ideal as the complexity to manage [to some degree] accurate count of `total` is not necessarily trivial (>= 0).  Depending on your context (for examples):

- `total` might not be updated often, so maybe the complexity is less severe
- Or else maybe `total` is updated frequently, so maybe that high updating [chattiness](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/14796/chatty-protocol) makes complexity more severe

Related to those examples also is the idea of [Data Freshness](https://www.networkworld.com/article/3281126/data-freshness-not-speed-most-important-for-iot.html):  Requiring "fresher" data would be when I referred there would be more chattiness complexity.  That being said, even if the underlying data being counted itself updates frequently, updating `total` can be intentionally "stale" (as opposed to fresh) and therefore then reduce chattiness still; although the managing of anything other than [maybe relatively] optimal freshness is a facet of complexity in itself.

So in general, choosing to architect a *solution involving this sort of top-level `total` should be confirmed worth the type of management complexity I've discussed here*.

Comment: Fwiw:  Many higher level languages' data structures for Collections can return their size in Constant O(1) time because they internally use the idea of a `total` variable similar to what I proposed as a possible solution here).  And they maintain accurate `total` in O(1) also by just incrementing/decrementing it along with the collection update action itself.  Of course that internal management instead does not cost any development complexity in its case, as it is implemented in the language/data structure itself :)